# set multiple constraint in textfield

Tags: java, validation, java-me

i want to set numeric as well as password validation in TextField.
here is my code.

```
public TextField getPinNo()
{
    if(pinno==null)
    {
        pinno= new TextField("PIN", null,4, TextField.PASSWORD);

        pinno.setConstraints(TextField.NUMERIC);
    }
    return pinno;
}
```

after setting numeric validation my password validation stop working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraints flags for the TextField object can be combined using the bitwise OR operator. As you can read at the [TextField](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/TextField.html#PASSWORD) API Doc:

```
The PASSWORD modifier can be combined with other input constraints by using the bit-wise OR operator (|).
```

So, the resulting code could look like:

```
public TextField getPinNo()
{
    if(pinno==null)
    {
        pinno= new TextField("PIN", null,4, TextField.PASSWORD | TextField.NUMERIC);

    }
    return pinno;
}
```

Comment: thanks buddy..it works..as i m new to java me.i have not refered the textfield api.sorry for that.